# How to skip test cases in a JUnit testsuite?

Tags: automated-testing, junit

I have created a JUnit test suite that has multiple test cases. A couple of these are for functionality that are currently under implementation. I want to skip these test cases. How do I skip tests cases with JUnit?

My suite code looks like:

```
package pack1;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
    pack1.TC01CL.class,
    pack1.TC02CL.class,
    pack1.TC03CL.class
})

public class TestAll {
}
```

Comment: Before asking questions please do some research yourself. Searching for "skip JUnit test" results in this JUnit documentation page: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. You need to import**

`import org.junit.Ignore;`

**2. Tag @Ignore is available in JUnit** - It will skip your test from executing

```
@Ignore
@Test
public void your_test_to_skipped() {
---;
---;
}
```